# SimpleXml_load_file to two dimensional array

Tags: xml, simplexml

Sorry about this question, maybe somwhere here in StackOverflow is answer for my question, but there is a way, to convert my xml file to two dimensional php array and keep xml node attributes in second dimension (Something like this : $colors['2']['en'] i mean $colors[colorid][lang])?
P.S Sorry for my bad english, this isn`t my native language.
Here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Colors>
    <Color id="1">
        <Name lang="lv" default="true">Sudraba</Name>
        <Name lang="en">Silver</Name>
        <Name lang="ru">Серебро</Name>
    </Color>
    <Color id="2">
        <Name lang="lv" default="true">Sarkans</Name>
        <Name lang="en">Red</Name>
    </Color>
    <Color id="3">
        <Name lang="lv" default="true">Melns</Name>
    </Color>
</Colors>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example. If you are choosing $sxml->Color[0], this method is selecting first Color element in xml document, but if you select like this $sxml->Color["0"], it is selecting by element's attribute. Sorry for my english, this is not my native language too:).

```
<?php

    $sxml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Colors>
        <Color id="1">
            <Name lang="lv" default="true">Sudraba</Name>
            <Name lang="en">Silver</Name>
            <Name lang="ru">Серебро</Name>
        </Color>
        <Color id="2">
            <Name lang="lv" default="true">Sarkans</Name>
            <Name lang="en">Red</Name>
        </Color>
        <Color id="3">
            <Name lang="lv" default="true">Melns</Name>
        </Color>
    </Colors>');

    echo $sxml->Color["1"]->Name[0];



    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but i need convertation to array :(